# QT QTableView does not update to database after adding QSqlRelation

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, qtableview

I am retrieving data from a Postgres database to a **QTableView**. I would like to change the data in this table. All works fine with the code below. Data is shown, editable and stored in the database when changed.

When I make the table-data a bit more user-friendly the data becomes *unmutable*....

Below is my code. I first *commented out* the three lines with the **QSqlRelation** and the **QSqlRelationalDelegate**. That works fine. But when I add these three lines however, I can see a *comboBox* and its data, but after a change nothing is updated to the database. The other fields are not stored as well.

What am I missing?

```cpp
void getInfo(QTableView* tv) {

    //! get connection
    auto db = QSqlDatabase::database();

    if (db.open())
    {   
        
        //! Declare model       
        QSqlRelationalTableModel* myModel = new QSqlRelationalTableModel;

        //! set tablename
        //! It retrieves a table with 4 columns:
        //! key(string), directory(string), paper_id(int), copy(bool)
        myModel->setTable("import.myinfo");

        //! Without the next three lines all works fine.
        //! The comboBox shows the paper_names(string) instead of a paper_id(int)
        QSqlRelation rel("import.paper_types", "paper_id", "paper_name");
        myModel->setRelation(2, rel);
        tv->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(tv));

        //! Get the data
        myModel->select();

        myModel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);

        tv->setModel(myModel);
        tv->resizeColumnsToContents();
        tv->show();

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Error = " << db.lastError().text();
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have modified the title into: **QSqlRelationalTableModel** stops being _read/write_ after adding a **QSqlRelation**.

Comment: I discovered that the example from **QT** in their **relationaltablemodel.cpp** does not update as well. The problem has to do with the _Model/View_ design. As soon as one uses _fieldnames_ and _lookupvalues_ from **foreign tables**, you have to write custom update-queries. For that you need to store the original _fieldnames_ and _values_ somewhere, especially when using compound primary keys.